# Difficulty outputting String with returned double

Tags: java

Below is a program, that I am having difficulty outputting the String message with the returned double values. Any help is greatly appreciated I am not sure where to go from here. I am probably over-thinking it or over-seeing a simple solution. Thankyou!

The expected output is:

```
average = 12.5  
average = 7.63  
average = 6.96
```

however my program is outputting:

```
12.5  
7.63  
6.96
```

Here is my code:

```
class Test2{
       public static void main(String[] args){
          int i, j;  
          double di, dj, dk;  
          i = 20;  
          j = 5;  
          Overload ol = new Overload();  
          System.out.println(ol.findAverage(i, j));  
          di = 14.29;  
          dj = 0.97;  
          System.out.println(ol.findAverage(di, dj));  
          di = 3.51;  
          dj = 13.5;  
          dk = 3.87;  
          System.out.println(ol.findAverage(di, dj, dk));
       }
    }

    class Overload {
       private int i, j;
       private double di, dj, dk;
       private double average;

       public double findAverage(int i, int j) {
          average = ((i + j) / 2.0);    
          return average;
       } 

       public double findAverage(double di, double dj) { 
          average = (di + dj) / 2.0; 
          return average;
       } 

       public double findAverage(double di, double dj, double dk) { 
          average = (di + dj + dk) / 3.0; 
          return average;
       }

       public String findAverage() {
          return "average = " + average;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, you call the wrong function when you do your output : you have to call findAverage()

Comment: As a side note: read about varargs https://www.javatpoint.com/varargs  and write one method to handle variable number of arguments: `findAverage(double... d)`

Answer (score 3):

When you call :

```
System.out.println(ol.findAverage(i, j));
```

Behind, you are calling

```
public double findAverage(int i, int j) {
      average = ((i + j) / 2.0);    
      return average;
   }
```

This function returns only the double calculated

If you want your correct output, simply do :

```
ol.findAverage(i, j);
System.out.println(ol.findAverage());
```

Comment: I sugest to rename ol.findAverage() to toString() which is much better to avoid ambiguity

Comment: That seems to work! However, I am not allowed to modify the Test2 class in anyway, so what I have there is what I have to work with. :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I seem to be calling the same method over again where it simply returns the average and not e.g. average = 12.5

Comment: ol.findAverage(di, dj, dk);
          System.out.println(ol.findAverage());

Comment: I cant figure out how to do it with the main that is provided, I have to use the main provided and I can't seem to figure it out